# Transferring contacts, calendars and applications from one device to another

Tags: applications, contacts, calendar

I am completing my contract on my EVO 4G and replacing it (with a Galaxy SII Epic 4G).
Both are Android - I am wondering what is the best way to transfer my contacts (a few thousand) and calendar (a few dozen) from the old to the new?

Also, I assume I have to install all apps one by one on the new device, any better ideas.

Comment: If you're using Google to sync your contacts and calendar you won't need to do anything. If you're not you should. I just moved from a Droid to a Galaxy Nexus and everything was seamless (including all of my apps) because of my Google account.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Google calendar and that the contacts aren't being stored on your SIM card, all you need to do is set up your new device with the same Google account that you used to set up the previous phone(s).  If you are storing the contacts on the SIM, there is an option in the contacts to move them to Google contacts.

As for installing your apps, any apps you've paid for will automatically download and reinstall from the Android Market (again, provided you use the same Google account on both devices).  You can also use services like [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) to create lists that you can then use to mass install apps on another device.

I would recommend using [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) to back apps up on one device to your SD card, then either transfer the SD card to the backup files to the new device, install Titanium Backup on the new device, and then restore from that.  That way you get too keep you settings for the apps, too.  Don't backup the system settings though, as going from one device model to another may be problematic.

Comment: Also, if you're moving between Android versions, I'd suggest restoring the apps from Titanium with "App only" instead of "App+data" to minimize application data incompatibility.