# How do I transfer all my contacts from HTC Wildfire to HTC One?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

My HTC Wildfire does not have an SD card. I am changing phones and providers, from HTC Wildfire on 3 Network to an HTC One on Vodafone. Please advise how I can transfer my contacts from my 3 Network sim card?

Comment: Back them up to Google, then your new phone will just download them from Google.  `Settings > Accounts > Google` and check `Contacts`

Comment: If I recall, HTC phone tend to come with an application for that. Backing them up to google is likely simpler however

Comment: Yep HTC do, but I found Google more reliable and easier. It also has the advantage that they will transfer to any other phone, not just a HTC. Google Synch will also import all the extra information HTC store in XML (link to Facebook, notes etc) about the contact. Once you backup you can go to http://www.google.com/contacts and ensure they are all there!

Comment: Does the phone automatically move contacts saved on the phone to Google contacts? I had to do this manually once by sending all contacts to my own Gmail as a vcard and importing to Google contacts in the web interface.

Comment: See: [Transferring contacts, calendars and applications from one device to another](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17416/16575) / [How to transfer apps, contacts and settings between two identical phones?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1686/16575) / [How can I transfer my all contacts from old HTC Wildfifre android 2.1 to LG Optimus Vu](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/52600/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you this HTC's official app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.htc.dnatransfer.legacy

Answer (score 0):

Some of the 3 methods,

1. Go to Accounts and Synch and then synch your contacts with your google account.
2. You could export all contacts in the .VCF format.
3. You could take a backup using a third party software such as [Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts)